# Inverse fourier transform involving exponentials

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse

I would like to calculate the inverse fourier transform of:

$$\hat{f}(k)=\exp(-a k^2+ikv)\cdot \frac{\sinh(m\sqrt{(b+ck^2+ikf)^2-d})}{\sqrt{(b+ck^2+ikf)^2-d}}$$

Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this for $d=0$?  If you got nowhere in that case, then you may as well set up that FFT now.

Comment: @RonGordon: I need the case d>0

Comment: I understand, but what I am saying is that if you cannot do the case $d=0$, then the case $d>0$ is hopeless in closed form.

Comment: @RonGordon: sorry, I understand it now. Thanks.